# gst_h264_parser_identify_nalu Not Finding NAL in Buffer

Tags: c, streaming, h.264, gstreamer

```
GstH264NalParser *parser = NULL;
GstH264NalUnit nal_unit = { 0 };

parser = gst_h264_nal_parser_new();
GstH264ParserResult parser_result = gst_h264_parser_identify_nalu(parser,
    buffer_map.data,
    0,
    buffer_map.size,
    &nal_unit); /* This returns GST_H264_PARSER_NO_NAL */
```

Why is that? Unless `data` is not supposed to come from a `GstMapInfo*` but some other data structure. A `GstStructure` pointer from a `GstSample`, perhaps?

**Context**

Writing a small program that parses h.264 encoded video from Gstreamer's videotestsrc and appsink plug-ins. So far, so good.

Using the (bad) x264enc plug-in in my pipeline to convert the stream before feeding it into an h264parse, then into appsink. Pretty sure the h264parse is an unnecessary step, but I get the same results with and without.

Convinced that am using incorrect struct to read data into NALU parse function.

Comment: Are you considering the `stream-format` and `alignment` properties in your caps?

Comment: `#define VIDEO_CAPS "video/h-x264,stream-format=(string)byte-stream,profile(string)=baseline"`

Comment: What would the preferred alignment be for something like smooth streaming?

Comment: I think I would do it differently: I would write a pipeline with encoder and finished by fakesink. I would then attach a probe callback on pad src of encoder in which you get the buffer. Hopefully, you will there be able to find NAL in buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe your incoming data is good, odds are you need to do a small conversion because in h264 streams there are a few different modes of encoding.

I'm not sure why that is, but you sometimes need to do a small conversion.  That is what the `h264parse` element is for.

`Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-h264
                 parsed: true
          stream-format: { avc, avc3, byte-stream }
              alignment: { au, nal }`

So in your pipeline you might try permutations on the stream-format and alignmnet options, such as:

`gst-launch videotestsrc ! ... ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=nal ! appsink`

Comment: When I `gst_app_sink_pull_sample` it seems h264parse somehow formats the sample differently. Could you give me a rough example of how to pull a sample when my appsink receives a new frame, while using h264parse?